# Java synchronization performance

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, readwritelock

I would like opinion on this to settle a small dispute. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have written my own file handler that is attached to the logger. This being a file handler and being accessed by multiple threads, I am using synchronization in order to ensure that there is no collision during the writing process. Additionally it is a rolling log, so I also close and open files, and do not want any problems there either.

His response to it was (as pasted from email)

> I strongly believe that Synchronization is very bad in the Handler. It
>   is too complex for such easy task. So, I would say why do not use one
>   instance per Thread?

What would you say is better from performance's and memory management perspective.
Thank you very much for any response. Whenever writing and reading is involved in multithreaded applications I have used synchronization on java applications all my life, and have not heard of any severe performance issues.

So please I would like to know if there are any issues and I really should switch to one instance per thread.

And in general, what would be the downfall of using synchronization?

EDIT: the reason why I wrote a custom file handler (yes I do love slf4j), is because my custom handler is dealing with two files at once, and additionally I have few other functions I perform on top of writing to files.

Comment: Theoretical discussions are fine (in theory (sic)).  But to answer this quantitatively you must *test* the performance (you could use [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) for this).  Synchronization does have performance implications - how severe this is depends on the contention between the threads for the guarded resource. 

I don't understand the "one instance per thread", does that mean a separate file per handler?

Comment: Why would you do any of this when log4j, slf4j, and apache commons logging all exist?  Hasn't logging been solved?  Why would you waste your time trying to improve on what's been done many times over?

Comment: I doubt any application will spend a lot of its run time on logging - so the performance is probably not even worth thinking about more than having a reliable solution. I highly doubt it's a bottleneck.

Comment: @earcam I guess he means create one handler per thread, that way they will not interfere. His explanation is still coming, but I am also not quote understanding it.

Comment: @Pescis Logging is in fact quite often a real-life performance threat, but also it is systematically controllable via logging level filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all I/O, you have little choice but mutual exclusion. You *may* theoretically build up a complex scheme with a lock-free queue which accumulates logging entries, but its utility, and especially its *reliability*, would be very questionable: without careful design you could get a logging-caused OOME, have the application hang on due to threads which you didn't clean up, etc.

Keep in mind that, assuming you are using buffered I/O, you already have an equivalent of a queue, minimizing the time spent occupying the lock.

Comment: and what is [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)

Comment: Why 'lock-free'?  There should be no reliablilty issue with queueing log entry objects to a producer-consumner queue with a log-write thread hanging off it, as suggested by @ratchetfreak.

Comment: It's not 'careful design' - it's fairly trivial.

Comment: @martin And what would be the gain compared to buffered IO?

Comment: @Martin Compared to a single synchronized keyword, hardly anything can be justified as "trivial".

Comment: @martin Some more dilemmas for your "trivial" approach: 1. why not reduce complexity to "beyond trivial" and use an `ExecutorService`? 2. do you plan to call `.toString` and `.printStackTrace` on your arguments in the calling or in the logging thread? There are potential pitfalls in both cases. 3. You are deploying into an application container which has an express policy against applications starting their own threads. What do you do?

Answer (score 5):

another solution would be to use a separate thread to do the (costly on its own) writing and use concurrent queues to pass the log messages from the domain threads

the key part here is that pushing to a queue is much less costly that writing to a file and means that there is less interference from concurrent log calls

the call to log would then log like

```
private static BlockingQueue logQueue = //...

public static void log(String message){
//construct&filter message
    logQueue.add(message);
}
```

then in the logger thread it will look like

```
while(true){
    String message = logQueue.poll();
    logFile.println(message);//or whatever you are doing
}
```

Comment: +1 = best reply so far.  A lock round pushing a log-request object  pointer onto a queue is hugely preferable to pissing around with each thread that needs to log trying to get some mutex.  LogRequestClass + BlockingQueue+logger thread is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

The downfall to synchronisation is the fact that only one thread can access that part of the code at any one time, meaning your code will see little benefit from multithreading I.e. the synchronised part of your application will only be as fast as a single thread. (Small overhead for handling the synchronised status too, so a little slower perhaps)

However, in subjects where you don't want the threads to interfere with one another, such as writing to files, the security gained from the synchronisation is paramount, and the performance loss should just be accepted.

Comment: Synchro of the actual disk writes can be avoided - see @ratchet freak.